Why does st_join(ob1, ob2, left = TRUE) return an sf object with more features than ob1?
I have two sf objects with multiple polygon features. The two objects have attributes that I would like to join to each other using the polygons. I have managed to do so with st_join(), but not in the way that I expected.
When using st_join(), I initially expected that if I specified the argument st_join(x, y, left = TRUE), that the resulting object would have the same number of features as x if all the geometries in x are contained in y. For example:
library("sf")
library("tidyverse")

map1 <- st_as_sfc(c("POLYGON((0 0 , 0 1 , -1 1 , -1 0, 0 0))",
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 2 , 2 2 , 2 0, 0 0 ))", 
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 -0.5 , -0.5 -0.5 , -0.5 0, 0 0))")) %>% 
  st_sf(ID = paste0("poly", 1:3),
        att1 = c(letters[1:3]))

map2 <- st_as_sfc(c("POLYGON((0 0 , 0 0.5 , -0.5 .5 , -0.5 0, 0 0))",
                    "POLYGON((-0.5 0 , -0.5 1 , -1 1 , -1 0 , -0.5 0))",
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 1 , 1 1 , 1 0 , 0 0))",
                    "POLYGON((1 1 , 1 2 , 2 2 , 2 1 , 1 1))",
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 -0.25 , -0.25 -0.25 , -0.25 0 , 0 0))")) %>% 
  st_sf(ID = paste0("poly", 4:8)) %>%
  mutate(att2 = c(LETTERS[1:5]))

map3 <- st_join(map2,
                map1,
                left = TRUE)

My expectation would be that map3 would have 5 features because all the polygons in map2 are contained uniquely in features of map1. This is however not the case, and polygons that do not overlap appear to have been joined with each other:
Simple feature collection with 12 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -1 ymin: -0.25 xmax: 2 ymax: 2
CRS:           NA
First 10 features:
     ID.x att2  ID.y att1                              .
1   poly4    A poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
1.1 poly4    A poly2    b POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
1.2 poly4    A poly3    c POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
2   poly5    B poly1    a POLYGON ((-0.5 0, -0.5 1, -...
2.1 poly5    B poly3    c POLYGON ((-0.5 0, -0.5 1, -...
3   poly6    C poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
3.1 poly6    C poly2    b POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
3.2 poly6    C poly3    c POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
4   poly7    D poly2    b POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 ...
5   poly8    E poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 -0.25, -0....

I have managed to get the expected result by using the argument largest = TRUE as follows:
map4 <- st_join(map2,
                map1,
                left = TRUE,
                largest = TRUE)


I however don't understand why this gives me the desired output but omitting largest = TRUE does not.
Thanks for taking the time to help!

Typically a join returns more rows than input when there are multiple matches. If data if polyA and polyB in map1 both overlap with polyC and polyD in map2, then when you join map1 and map2 those 2 rows will become 4, because every overlapping combination is joined. When you set largest = TRUE, instead of joining every overlap, only the largest overlap is joined, so the number of rows is maintained.

I'd also add that due often to floating point precision issues, it is hard to be precise about what overlaps and what doesn't if polygons are very close/touching.

Regarding the close vote (Not reproducible or was caused by a typo 1) , example in question is complete and reproducible, the result is as expected but might not be intuitive if one is not too familiar with different spatial predicates.

Does this answer your question? Using st_join for a spatial join using largest intersection

Default predicate for st_join() is st_intersects, which is also TRUE for touching geometries.

intersects - A and B are not disjoint
disjoint   - A and B have no points in common
( https://r-spatial.org/book/03-Geometries.html#sec-de9im )

In your case, you seem to be after st_within.

within     -    None of the points of B are outside A

Lets first visualize how those features relate:
library("sf")
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library("tidyverse")

map1 <- st_as_sfc(c("POLYGON((0 0 , 0 1 , -1 1 , -1 0, 0 0))",
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 2 , 2 2 , 2 0, 0 0 ))", 
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 -0.5 , -0.5 -0.5 , -0.5 0, 0 0))")) %>% 
  st_sf(ID = paste0("poly", 1:3),
        att1 = c(letters[1:3]))

map2 <- st_as_sfc(c("POLYGON((0 0 , 0 0.5 , -0.5 .5 , -0.5 0, 0 0))",
                    "POLYGON((-0.5 0 , -0.5 1 , -1 1 , -1 0 , -0.5 0))",
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 1 , 1 1 , 1 0 , 0 0))",
                    "POLYGON((1 1 , 1 2 , 2 2 , 2 1 , 1 1))",
                    "POLYGON((0 0 , 0 -0.25 , -0.25 -0.25 , -0.25 0 , 0 0))")) %>% 
  st_sf(ID = paste0("poly", 4:8)) %>%
  mutate(att2 = c(LETTERS[1:5]))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = map1, aes(fill = "map1"), linewidth = 5,) +
  geom_sf(data = map2, aes(fill = "map2"), color = "white", , linewidth = 1, alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf_label(data = map1, aes(label = ID, fill = "map1")) +
  geom_sf_label(data = map2, aes(label = ID, fill = "map2"), color = "white") +
  theme_minimal()


With st_join(... , join = st_intersects) (default):

st_join(map2, map1, left = TRUE, join = st_intersects)
#> Simple feature collection with 12 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -1 ymin: -0.25 xmax: 2 ymax: 2
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 10 features:
#>      ID.x att2  ID.y att1                              .
#> 1   poly4    A poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
#> 1.1 poly4    A poly2    b POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
#> 1.2 poly4    A poly3    c POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
#> 2   poly5    B poly1    a POLYGON ((-0.5 0, -0.5 1, -...
#> 2.1 poly5    B poly3    c POLYGON ((-0.5 0, -0.5 1, -...
#> 3   poly6    C poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
#> 3.1 poly6    C poly2    b POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
#> 3.2 poly6    C poly3    c POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
#> 4   poly7    D poly2    b POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 ...
#> 5   poly8    E poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 -0.25, -0....

With st_join(... , join = st_within):
st_join(map2, map1, left = TRUE, join = st_within)
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -1 ymin: -0.25 xmax: 2 ymax: 2
#> CRS:           NA
#>    ID.x att2  ID.y att1                              .
#> 1 poly4    A poly1    a POLYGON ((0 0, 0 0.5, -0.5 ...
#> 2 poly5    B poly1    a POLYGON ((-0.5 0, -0.5 1, -...
#> 3 poly6    C poly2    b POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 ...
#> 4 poly7    D poly2    b POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 ...
#> 5 poly8    E poly3    c POLYGON ((0 0, 0 -0.25, -0....

Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0
